# Showing Tool-tip on mouse-over using Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, jquery-plugins, jquery-tooltip

I have tool-tip that pops up on mouse over but what i would like to see is to show the tool-tip on specific column only like when i mouse over on column 2.  Currently, the tool-tip is showing up on every column and that a bit distracting.  Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
        runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-family: Arial;
        }
        .tooltip
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 3;
            display: none;
            background-color: #FB66AA;
            color: White;
            padding: 5px;
            max-width: 150px;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-family: Arial;

        }
        td
        {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.simpletip-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('[id*=GridView1] tr').each(function () {
                var toolTip = $(this).attr("title");
                $(this).find("td").each(function () {
                    $(this).simpletip({
                        content: toolTip
                    });
                });
                $(this).removeAttr("title");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and here is my code behind:

```
 protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.ToolTip = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView)["Description"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are adding tooltip on row.if you want to add tooltip to cell try following code

```
e.Row.Cells[1].ToolTip = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView)["Description"].ToString();
```

**Update**
Check out following link for complete example

[Using the jQuery Tooltip Plugin in a GridView](http://chinmayaparija.blogspot.in/2011/12/using-jquery-tooltip-plugin-in-gridview.html)

Comment: thanks, but when i add the tooltip to cell[1], it shows the tooltip but it is without the style sheet that i created like the white background and it disappears right away.  Also, when i mouse over the other columns the tool-tip still showing up with the style sheet i created but without any info inside the tool-tip. The only info is showing inside the tool-tip is "A Simple Tool-tip" for all other columns.

Comment: i would like to show the tool-tip for col[1] with the style sheet i created and i don't want to show any tool-tip if there is no tool-tip info for that row, just show nothing.  thanks for your help.